# TextArea text formatting not changing in Flash CS5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

**Prologue**
I am studying Flash and want to make a video player with where you can change video and the corresponding subtitles with a click on either "forward" or "back" button.

So far I have created 2 arrays of video files ("[videos]") and text strings ("[captions]"). By clicking on one of the buttons, the video in the FLVPlayback component changes as well as the the subtitles-text in the TextArea.

However I have a problem with text formatting.

I use the following functions for button click:

```
   function playNextVideo():void
   {
   if (currentVideo < videos.length-1)
    {
    currentVideo++;
    playCurrentVideo();
    }
   }

   function playCurrentVideo():void
   {
    textCaption.textField.defaultTextFormat = newFormat;
    textCaption.textField.text=captions[currentVideo];
    myVideo.source = videos[currentVideo];
    myVideo.play();
   }
```

The newFormat is a simple TextFormat variable:

```
var newFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

newFormat.color = 0x0000C9;
newFormat.size = 18;
newFormat.italic = true;
```

I execute playCurrentVideo() to start the video playback.

**The Problem**
My problem is that the format changes only when I click the button, but it is not applied for the first subtitle.

So, for the first video I get a plain text, with black color, not italic and not with size "18".
However, if I click on "forward" button (and thus execute the playCurrentVideo() again), the format will change. If I then will try to go back to the first video, the text will now be formatted.

So my question is - what causes this condition and how to handle it?

Comment: Can you post more code? You have an instantiation problem by the looks of it, and it's difficult to discern where without seeing more of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the TextArea you are using is one of flash components then you need to call:

```
textCaption.setStyle( "textFormat", newFormat );
```

Your code would look now as:

```
 function playCurrentVideo():void {
textCaption.setStyle( "textFormat", newFormat );
textCaption.text=captions[currentVideo];
myVideo.source = videos[currentVideo];
myVideo.play();
```

}

Comment: I did it the following way:

var newFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

newFormat.color = 0x0000C9;
newFormat.size = 18;
newFormat.font = "Times"

textCaption.setStyle("textFormat", newFormat);

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it has something to do with the way TextField is implemented.  When you change  a TextField's properties, you sometimes have to wait one frame until the changes apply. 
Try to set `defaultTextFormat = newFormat` at the time the TextField is instantiated, and/or `setTextFormat(newFormat)` after the text is changed.